# reset only one wizard in redux-from

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-form

I have a "Wizard Form" created by redux-form in reactjs website

in the form, my wizards name's are "A" and "B"

my website's user will complete wizard "A" and will click on "go to wizard B" button, and in wizard "B" will complete some of fields, but for some reason he will decided to came back to wizard "A" to change some fields in the wizard "A", so he will click on "back to wizard A" button.

my question is how can i reset only wizard "B" form, when user click on "back to wizard A" button?

Comment: How do you reset the whole state now?

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi, with this code:
this.props.reset()
only use this code in your form file

Comment: so simply don't do that, and find a way to delete only parts that you need. there inot even one line of code to show what you are doing. if  `reset` is a redux-form function it might have other functions too

Answer (score 0):

`wizard A` and `wizard B` should be 2 instances of `reduxForm` decorator and `wizardA` should have `destroyOnUnmount` set to `false`:

```
const wizardA = reduxForm({
  form: 'wizardA' // a unique identifier for this form
  destroyOnUnmount: false,
})(SomeForm)

const wizardB = reduxForm({
  form: 'wizardB'
})(SomeForm2)
```

this will allow you to store the information that the user entered in `wizardA` form even after switching to `wizardB` form.